How to up-/download a file to/from sharepoint through a .NET MAUI App
I'm currently building a .NET MAUI app and I was wondering if and how it is possible to access a sharepoint site through this app. I already managed to implement a login to gather an access token, but now I'm not really sure what to do with it. Can't find any tutorials on this.
I tried to do it using the Microsoft.Graph package but with no success, however I think that this is the right approach.
Eventually I'm trying to display all the folders from one site so the user can pick one and then upload data to this specific folder.
Any help, tips, hints are appreciated! Thanks in advance!
Best wishes,
Lukas

https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+upload+download+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Microsoft Graph exposes REST APIs and client libraries that can access data on SharePoint. What issues have you encountered when using the Microsoft.Graph package?

You can refer to SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph. The document provides a sample to explain how to use the SharePoint API in Microsoft Graph
